# From bat - open cmd, load doskey macros, and execute a macro

Tags: batch-file, macros, cmd, piping, doskey

Is it possible to use `cmd /k "doskey /macrofile=C:\myMacros.cmd && macroCommand"` from a bat file.

I have tried that as well as `start cmd.exe /k "doskey /macrofile=C:\myMacros.cmd && macroCommand"`. How can I make this work?

I googled a little and found something about piping, but I don't even know what this is, and even after researching that a little, I don't see how this would help run a macro after starting cmd and loading macros.

Comment: Well, I kind of got around what I needed to do. I had a doskey macro that called a bat file, so I just call the bat file before I use `cmd /k...`

Answer (score 0):

assuming macros.cmd reside in %userprofile% and in the form of macro list

running :

```
start cmd /k "(doskey /macrofile=%userprofile%\macros.cmd)"
```

will get you what you wanted e.g. open a new cmd window loaded with the predefined macros